# Help in connecting with Hyperledger fabric network deployed on AWS managed blockchain

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to connect my network created on AWS managed blockchain in my Node JS server. I have the private hyper-ledger fabric network in the AWS managed blockchain. It seems there is no official or right docs for the connection to the blockchain network.

Could anyone guide me how can i connect with my network?

Also, for detail overview. My main purpose is to connect with a network, create a channel there, then deploy a custom assets crud based chaincode and then deploy that as well. Later i want to access the chaincode using rest api. What is the procedure for whole of this purpose?

Comment: Would https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/fabric-sdks.html be the resource you're looking for? I followed https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/build-and-deploy-an-application-for-hyperledger-fabric-on-amazon-managed-blockchain/ there.

Comment: Actually I was able to do what you mentioned in the comment. I am actually having issue connecting with network on my local env. I am able to connect with the AWS ec2 instance. But i want to connect using my local env from local device to connect to the network using node js. The ca authority certificate cannot be accessed outside the aws region. Do you have idea about that?